# how to get only overlapping records based on start and end date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have a table and query as follow:
I am trying to get overlapping records between `[Assignment Start Date]` and `[Assignment End Date]` for same `Employee Id`.
In short I need data for those `Employee Id` which are allocated for same time period or overlapping time period from below example.
e.g.

```
  [Employee Id]   [Assignment Start Date]     [Assignment End Date]   [Allocation Percentage]

        100                2016-03-01                 2017-02-28             100
        102                2016-06-01                 2016-12-31             100
        102                2016-07-01                 2016-10-30             100
        102                2016-11-01                 2017-01-31             100
        103                2017-02-01                 2017-05-30             100
        102                2017-04-01                 2017-06-30             100
        102                2017-11-01                 2017-01-31             100
        104                2017-02-01                 2017-05-01             100



CREATE TABLE #Result
(
PK INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[BU] VARCHAR(20),
[Division] VARCHAR(20),
[Product Name] VARCHAR(30),
[Employee ID] NVARCHAR(20),
[Resource Name] VARCHAR(50),
[Resource_ID] INT,
[Assignment Start Date] DATE,
[Assignment End Date] DATE,
[Allocation Percentage] INT,
[Location] VARCHAR(100),
[Development Manager] VARCHAR(50),
[Allocation] VARCHAR(20)
);


SELECT  DISTINCT r1.PK, r1.Resource_ID,r1.[Employee ID], r1.[Assignment Start Date] AS 'Start 1' ,r1.[Assignment End Date] AS 'End 1' , r2.[Assignment Start Date] , r2.[Assignment End Date]
INTO #temp1
FROM #Result r1

INNER JOIN #Result r2
ON r1.[Employee ID] = r2.[Employee ID]
AND (r1.PK <> r2.PK)
AND ((r1.[Assignment Start Date] <= r2.[Assignment Start Date]) AND (r1.[Assignment End Date] >= r2.[Assignment Start Date]))
OR ((r1.[Assignment Start Date] > r2.[Assignment Start Date] AND r1.[Assignment Start Date] <= r2.[Assignment End Date]) AND (r1.[Assignment End Date] <= r2.[Assignment End Date]))
OR ((r1.[Assignment Start Date] > r2.[Assignment Start Date] AND r1.[Assignment Start Date]  <= r2.[Assignment End Date]) AND (r1.[Assignment End Date] > r2.[Assignment End Date]))
OR (r1.[Assignment Start Date]  = r2.[Assignment End Date])
```

I have tried using above query but it gives all records related to overlapping employee even if that entry for that employee is not overlapping.

In above example there is a `Employee Id` `102` which has 2 overlapping entries and 3rd entry which is not overlapping I want to remove it from this result. please help.

Comment: What if `102` had a pair of two overlapping records?  What would your expected output be?

Comment: if any of the records is overlapping with other then both overlapping record should be in result.. none overlapping should not be in result. to your question both pair should be in result.

Comment: Who ever down voted the question please give a reason !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE, row_number and a self join

```
with CTE as
(
select PK, Resource_ID, [Employee ID] as Emp_ID, [Assignment Start Date] as s_Date, [Assignment End Date] as e_date,
       row_number() over(partition by [Employee ID] order by  [Assignment Start Date] ) as rn
from #Result
)
select t1.*, t2.*
from CTE t1
inner join CTE t2
  on t1.Resource_ID = t2.Resource_ID
  and t1.Emp_ID = t2.Emp_ID
  and t2.rn = t1.rn +1
where t2.s_date <= t1.e_date 
or t1.e_date is null -- allows for null end date
```

Comment: It says invalid column name 'rn'  @t2.rn = t1.rn + 1

Comment: @NikhilPatel My bad, I wasn't referencing the CTE correctly. Edited

Comment: Thanks for correction .. your answer worked but partially... I m getting overlapping records but it does not give me pair... It return only one of the overlapping record.

Comment: @NikhilPatel reference the second pass at the CTE for the second set, as per the latest edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer I got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should look like that below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.PK, r1.Resource_ID,r1.[Employee ID], r1.[Assignment Start Date] AS 'Start 1' ,r1.[Assignment End Date] AS 'End 1' , r2.[Assignment Start Date] , r2.[Assignment End Date]
INTO #temp1
FROM #Result r1
JOIN #Result r2 on r1.[Employee ID] = r2.[Employee ID]
WHERE (
(r2.[Assignment Start Date]  BETWEEN r1.[Assignment Start Date]  and r1.[Assignment End Date])
or
(r2.[Assignment End Date] between p1.[Assignment Start Date]  and p1.[Assignment End Date])
)
AND r1.PK <> r2.PK
```